# How to align dimensions to use np.dot() between two different matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use the dot product in Numpy between two matrices with different dimensions.
w is (1, 5) and X is (3, 5)
I'm not sure which command I can use to change the dimensions as I am new to python.
Thank you.

When I try running my function, it gives me an error saying:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,5) and (3,5) not aligned: 5 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

```
from numpy.core.memmap import ndarray
def L(w, X, y):
    """
    Arguments:
    w -- vector of size n representing weights of input features n
    X -- matrix of size m x n represnting input data, m data sample with n features each 
    y -- vector of size m (true labels)
  
    Returns:
    loss -- the value of the loss function defined above
    """
    
    ### START CODE HERE ### (2-4 lines of code)
    #w needs to match X matrix
    # w = (1, 5)
    # x = (3, 5)
    yhat = np.dot(w, X)
    L1 = y - yhat
    loss = np.dot(L1, L1)

    
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    return loss
```

Here is the picture of directions:
[image of directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLV7S.png)

Comment: The (1,5) can multiply a (5,3) to give a (1,3).You may need to `transpose`

Comment: Read, and reread, the `np.dot` docs.  It is clear about how dimensions should align.

Answer (score 1):

The dot product of two vectors is the sum of the products of elements with regards to position. The first element of the first vector is multiplied by the first element of the second vector and so on. The sum of these products is the dot product which can be done with **np.dot() function**.

> Since we multiply elements at the same positions, the two vectors must have same length in order to have a dot product.

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) 
b = np.array([[11,12],[13,14]]) 
np.dot(a,b)
```

It will produce the following output −

```
[[37  40] 
 [85  92]]
```

Note that the dot product is calculated as −

```
[[1*11+2*13, 1*12+2*14],[3*11+4*13, 3*12+4*14]]
```

Comment: Hey, appreciate your comment. But, I do know how dot product works, and that matrices of different dimensions cannot be multiplied by np.dot(). My problem is that I'm not sure which command I can use to change dimensions of the matrices (1,3) and (1, 5)

Comment: You can follow ::
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html
https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-dot/

Answer (score 0):

You get the full flexibility with [**tensordot**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) which implements tensor products with arbitrary choice of axes.

A nice application is estimating the covariance matrix, without messing with transpositions:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

dist = multivariate_normal(mean=[0,0],cov=[[1,1],[1,2]])
samples = dist.rvs(1000,2)
np.tensordot(samples,samples,axes=[0,0])/len(samples) # close to [[1,1],[1,2]
```